# cname configuration in dnsmasq

Tags: dnsmasq

I am trying to set up dnsmasq on my test VM to map calls to *.googleapis.com to *.private.googleapis.com as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access-hybrid#config-domain). I cannot get storage.googleapis.com to resolve to storage.private.googleapis.com through a CNAME record

My dnsmasq.conf looks like this

> listen-address=::1,127.0.0.1
> auth-server=localhost
> address=/private.googleapis.com/199.36.153.8
> address=/private.googleapis.com/199.36.153.9
> address=/private.googleapis.com/199.36.153.10
> address=/private.googleapis.com/199.36.153.11
> cname=*.googleapis.com,private.googleapis.com

my /etc/resolv.conf

> nameserver 127.0.0.1
> nameserver 8.8.4.4
> nameserver 8.8.8.8

> dig storage.private.googleapis.com

resolves as expected to 199.36.153.8/30 but

> dig storage.googleapis.com

does not resolve to the same addresses and is resolved through the public 8.8 name servers.

What am I missing? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here. I think dnsmasq may not be the best tool to accomplish this. I created a private zone in bind with the config below and I was able to access Google Cloud Storage through the private APIs. On CentOS 7.7 (/var/named/googleapis.com.zone):

```
$TTL 1D

@   IN SOA  node-bind-server.mydomain.com.   root.node-bind-server.mydomain.com. (
                                       2017031301      ; serial
                                       1D              ; refresh
                                       1H              ; retry
                                       1W              ; expire
                                       3H )            ; minimum

googleapis.com. IN      NS      node-bind-server.mydomain.com.
private.googleapis.com.  IN      A       199.36.153.8
private.googleapis.com.  IN      A       199.36.153.9
private.googleapis.com.  IN      A       199.36.153.10
private.googleapis.com.  IN      A       199.36.153.11
*.googleapis.com.       IN      CNAME   private.googleapis.com.
```

and my /etc/named.conf references this file

```
zone "googleapis.com" IN {
        type master;
        file "googleapis.com.zone";
};
```

and my named version

```
[root@node-bind-server etc]# named -v
BIND 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-26.P2.el7_9.13 (Extended Support Version) <id:7107deb>
```